# windows phone 8.1 apn constructor initialization error

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

[image: constructor-initilization error]

Can some windows phone 8.1 programmer check the issue with the initialization of
"cellularapncontext" api and solve the problem,I mean what does it need to fix the issue.

Comment: Can Someone with vs2013 check it out for me?

Comment: Looks like there is no public constructor defined for the class you are trying to create an instance of.